# Jquery selector to find thead

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="mytable>
        <thead> <tr> ...... </tr> </thead>
        <tbody> <tr> ...... </tr> </thead>
        <thead> <tr> ...... </tr> </thead> // how to remove this thead using jquery?
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to remove second `thead` from the table `mytable`. What would be the selector for this? I have tried with this.

```
$("#mytable").find("thead").eq(1) // not working or by using nth-child for thead still not working
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)** for removing the dom element

```js
$("#mytable").find("thead").eq(1).remove()
// or
// $("#mytable thead:eq(1)").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr><td>. First THead .</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td> TBody </td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>.Last THead.</td></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```